# uninitialized constant - RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The folder structure is as follows.

[image]

books_controller.rb is defined as follows.

```
module Api

  module V1

   class BooksController < ApplicationController
```

The checkout method inside books controler is defined as follows.

```
  def checkout
    begin

      @stripe = StripeService.new
      @stripe.invoke_payment

    rescue Stripe::CardError => e
      json_response(e.message, :unprocessable_entity)
    end
  end
```

But it is returning the following error

> NameError (uninitialized constant
>   Api::V1::BooksController::StripeServie):

stripe_service.rb

```
class StripeService



  def invoke_payment
    customer = fetch_customer
    save_user_card_info(customer)
    initiate_payment(customer.id)
  end
```

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: is this a typo "StripeServie.new"? do you mean StripeServiCe?

Comment: is `StripeServie` any model?

Comment: Show the definition of `StripeServie`.

Comment: You have just changed the question, and I am suspicious that you actually get the error message with `StripeServie` that you claim from what you say you have in your code (after the edit).

Comment: It was indeed a typo: I was calling StripeServie instead of StripeService.  Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be a typo: `StripeService` not `StripeServie`.

Or check the file name of `StripeServie` class and see it is `stripe_servie.rb`. Rails automatically loads all classes under `app` directory.